# Using class member as a class name to access static members

Tags: php, class, properties, static, classname

I know it's rather a rare case but I want to use a class property to hold my class name and then access it's static members through the property. Here is an example of what I want:

```
class a{
    private $className = "User";
    public function list(){
         $this->className::model()->findAll(); // error occurs here!
         // equal to 
         //  User::model()->findAll();
    }
}
```

So far I have tried every possibility and the only thing that has worked is using a scope variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
$class = $this->className;
$class::model()->findAll();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I already knew it, I'm looking for a way to do it, without scope variables

Comment: You can also use `call_user_func` like this:  `call_user_func(array($this->className, 'model'))->findAll();`